# Proof of Sets Using Logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to show $$(A \cup B) \setminus (B \cup C) =  A \setminus (B \cup C)$$ using logic?
I have been attempting this backwards and forwards but can't seem to reach a conclusion. 
I have tried to start from $A \setminus (B \cup C)$ to proof $(A \cup B) \setminus (B \cup C)$ but it leads to $(A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$.
Please enlighten me.

Comment: What tools can you use?  Naively, start from the assumption that $x \in (A\cup B) \setminus (B\cup C)$.  Then what? (e.g. it must be the case that $x \in A\cup B$, and that $x \not\in B\cup C$.)  Eventually, you should be able to show that $x \in A\setminus (B\cup C)$ (which means what, exactly?).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use the following:

$$
A\cup B =\{x\vert (x\in A) \ or \ (x\in B  \}
$$

and

$$
A\setminus B=\{x\vert (x\in A) \ and \ (x\notin B)  \}.
$$

Hope this helped